# svn create patch from multiple revisions

Tags: svn, patch, revisions

If I have changes, commited in revisions 11, 13 , 17, 20 into a branch, can I create an svn patch like this ?

svn diff -r11:20

Comment: See the answer for this similar Stackoverflow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25283101/1127583

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but don't forget path, which you diffing, canonical 1-st form of `svn diff`, JFYI, is:

```
diff [-c M | -r N[:M]] [TARGET[@REV]...]
```

Comment: what about changes made in revision 12 15 16 and 17 ? will they be in the patch too ?

Comment: @treefrog - patch collects **only** path-related changes, if mentioned  revisions are ouside diff-tree they will be ignored

Comment: What if the revision 12, 15, 16 and 17 are in the path but are irrelevant to the patch I want to create? Can we selectively ignore them?

Comment: @MukulGupta - it *this* case you have to use `-c`'s and enumerate all needed revisions

Comment: @LazyBadger: But svn can't take multiple `-c` arguments

Comment: @MukulGupta - wrong. Extraction from `svn help merge` "You can also cherry-pick several revisions and/or revision ranges:   `svn merge -c50,54,60 -r65:68 ^/trunk`"

Comment: @LazyBadger: Ok. Thanks. I had meant using `svn diff` and not `svn merge`. I want to generate a patch from previous commits. I do not want `merge` to generate the patch and apply it.

Answer (score 1):

this should be enough :)

```
svn diff -rFIRSTREVISION:LATESTREVISION pathOfWorkingCopy > /myPatchFile.patch
```