# Create "patch" between revisions?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, patch

It seems SVN's "patch" functionality is not exactly what I want. What I really want is to create a diff of files between revisions. So, I'd choose rev1 and rev 2 and end up with a folder containing all files that were changed or added between those revisions.

Can this be done with Tortoise SVN or plain-old svn?

Comment: what about files that were deleted between the two revisions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This can be achieved in tortoise SVN itself. Right click on the branch(folder) from where you want to create the patch >> `Show Log` >> Select All the revisions for which you need to create the patch >> Right Click and select `Compare revisions` >> This will show the changed files >> Select all the files >> Right click and select `Export Revision To` >> Give any path in your machine >> The files will get exported in the respective folder structure.

Alternately you can achieve this via scripting. Refer the following link for that:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli

Comment: Or instead of `Export Revision To`, you can choose `Show differences as unified diff` to create a patch file.

Answer (score 33):

From the command line you could do this as follows.

#### All files in a folder

Create a patch in your Home folder that contains all the changes between revision 123 and 124 from all the changed files in the folder "my_project":

```
svn diff -r123:124 path/to/my_project > ~/my_project_changes_123_124.patch
```

#### One particular file

Create a patch in your Home folder that contains all the changes between revision 123 and 124 from only one file, name "my_project.php":

```
svn diff -r123:124 path/to/my_project/my_project.php > ~/my_project_changes_123_124.patch
```

Comment: I don't want a "patch" file, I wanted the raw files that changes between the revisions. The accepted answer solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: To make a patch between current revision and an old revision 116615 you can do:    

    svn diff -r 116615 {svn-branch-url} > file.diff

Answer (score 4):

Um...how about `svn diff`? Just pass it the desired revisions.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html

In TortoiseSVN, if you highlight the revisions you want in the "show log" dialog, there is even a context menu item to show the changes as diff which you can then save off somewhere.

Comment: I don't want a "patch" file, I wanted the raw files that changes between the revisions. The accepted answer solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, so by "diff of files" you really meant "list of files that changed". Yes?

Comment: No, the actual files that changes. The accepted answer accomplishes this. Thanks!