# Svn diff patch containing all modified files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using subversion with visual svn server and tortoise svn and php.

My problem is:
I have a development network, where everything works just fine.
Due to corporate policy the production environment is phisically NOT connected to DEV. Nor does it have svn (and cannot change this fact).

Question:
Is it possible to create a diff patch (like a directory with files, or a single zip file), that actually contains all the changed files (in proper directory structure) between two revisions?

(I understand that i could not tell if a file is deleted etc, but at the moment i have to gather all the files manually, per directory)

Any other ideas for this?

thx

EDIT:

solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325654/6868878

Answer (score 0):

How do you compare the file systems? BeyondCompare is a big advantage when comparing folders. But I didn't use it with command line (don't know if this is possible).